# Getting Response From in Background URLSession Post

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm executing a post that could take a few seconds to come back and what to enable background mode. I'm trying to figure out if the app goes into the background while waiting on the post to return can I get the response somehow?

```
let bgSessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)
bgSessionConfig.sharedContainerIdentifier = "myid"
backgroundSessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: bgSessionConfig)
```

So basically will the completionHandler below ever get called if in the background?

```
sessionManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: dataParameters, encoding: parameterEncoding, headers: finalHeaders)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON(queue: self.dispatchQueue, completionHandler: {response in

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion handler in `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` is not something that "gets called". It is something that *you* must call when `urlSessionDidFinishEvents` arrives. What "gets called" is `handleEvents` itself. Your job here is to specify the background URL session (possibly creating it if you were just launched) and make yourself its delegate, immediately. *That* is how you will be contacted, through the normal delegate messages.

You would have received certain delegate messages if this had *not* been a background session; well, now you will receive those delegate messages when this *is* a background session.

Comment: This is tricky enough that you might need to see a working example. It happens to be a download task, not a post upload, but the principle is exactly the same. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p846backgroundDownload/ch37p1100backgroundDownload/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response! A little more info is that the original urlsession is launched from a Share Extension. When I try to recreate the above urlsession in handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession, I get "A background URLSession with identifier "myid" already exists.

Comment: But that was not in the question you asked. I answered the question you asked. If you have a different question ask it separately.